# Git version in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I use VS 2013, which, as I know, integrates with Git using its own libraries (libgit2, libgit2sharp).

When I run Git Bash, I see the version of the installed Git is 1.8.3-previewXXX, not sure, though, whether this version was installed by Visual Studio, or at the time when I installed 3-rd party Git tools upon the VS request.

The question is: does VS use this Git 1.8.3 installed in `Program Files/Git` through its libraries (libgit2, libgit2sharp), or Git for VS is something separate? And, if I update Git to version 1.9.0 as available on http://git-scm.com, will it affect Visual Studio Git integration, in particular, will there be issues or will VS just use new version of Git?

Comment: as far as I know those libraries don't care about your local environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Visual Studio Tools for Git" page does mention:

> Your msysgit installed version shouldn't have any impact whatsoever on the Visual Studio Git tools; we rely on the **[libgit2 library](http://libgit2.github.com/)**, which isn't packaged with msysgit.

But if you want to be sure, instead of upgrading, you simply can unzip a more recent version of msysgit wherever you want, and add that to your `%PATH%`.
I use for instance [`PortableGit-1.9.4-preview20140929.7z`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.4-preview20140929/PortableGit-1.9.4-preview20140929.7z).

Comment: The releases are no longer hosted on Google code. They can be found here: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases